# What is the distinction between asha and Deathseekers?

Tags: the-bone-witch

In the Bone Witch series by Rin Chupeco, there are, among other types of magic users, asha and Deathseekers. Asha tend to be female, and Deathseekers male.

It's a little unclear what the real distinctions in their magic are, though.

- It's clear that Deathseekers can use all the elemental runes, just as asha can.
- Supposedly, of all the runes in the book of the Faceless, only the heartshare rune can be used by Deathseekers.
- Except, the Puppet and Illusion runes were there too, and didn't we see Usijj (male) using both of them?
- Deathseekers are said to be less common than asha.
- Likh became an asha, even though he was male, but it's not clear whether this meant anything with regard to his powers.

Are there any real differences in the powers asha and Deathseekers can wield? In their birth rate? Is it all just convention, or is there more to it?